# How to apply a function to a multidimensional array based on its indices

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, indices

I have a 4 dimensional array and I want to fill in the slots with values which are a function of the inputs. Through searching the forums here I found that the function "outer" is helpful for 2x2 matrices but cannot be applied to general multidimensional arrays. Is there anything which can achieve this in R more efficiently than the following code ?

```
K <- array(0,dim=c(2,2,2,2)) #dimensions will be much larger
for(x1 in 1:2)
{
  for(y1 in 1:2)
  {
    for(x2 in 1:2)
    {
      for(y2 in 1:2)
      {
        K[x1,y1,x2,y2] <- x1*y2 - sin(x2*y1) #this is just a dummy function.
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Sorry, this is for the R programming language. As you can see, I'm new here and I think I bungled my question by not putting it in the right place or something. Still, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: OK - I have added an `r` tag for you - this should help to catch the attention of people with knowledge of `R` who might be able to answer your question.

Comment: don't have time right now, but you might look at the `tensor` package, which has a single function (`tensor`) that generalizes `outer` to multi-dimensional arrays ... may take a bit of fooling around to get it right

Answer (score 3):

Edit; Here's what I think will be an even faster solution. It assumes that you have predefined K as you offered. It uses the `K[] <-` construct to insert values calculated on a dataframe environment. Using the square-brackets on the LHS of the assignment preserves K's structure, and I think it is both vectorized and self-documenting:

```
dfm <- expand.grid(x1=1:2,x2=1:2,y1=1:2,y2=1:2) 
K[] <- with(dfm, x1*y2 - sin(x2*y1 ) )
```

First solution offered:
If you can create a data.frame or matrix that has the indices x1,x2,y1,y2 and the values you can use the: K[cbind(index-vectors)] <- values construction:

```
mtx<- data.matrix( expand.grid(x1=1:2,x2=1:2,y1=1:2,y2=1:2) )
K[mtx] <- apply(mtx, 1, function(x) x["x1"]*x["y2"] - sin(x['x2']*x['y1']) )
#----------------
> K
, , 1, 1

        [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 0.158529 0.09070257
[2,] 1.158529 1.09070257

, , 2, 1

          [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 0.09070257 1.756802
[2,] 1.09070257 2.756802

, , 1, 2

        [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 1.158529 1.090703
[2,] 3.158529 3.090703

, , 2, 2

        [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 1.090703 2.756802
[2,] 3.090703 4.756802
```